# How to pass a value within two functions without showing the errors?

Tags: python

So I was assigned to create an ordering application using Python. I can pass the login function to log in to the program and print "Welcome {user}", but when calling that the passenger is the username used to login on the get_passenger function, the program instead crashes and produces the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/fadhil/Downloads/getpassenger.py", line 36, in  main()
File "/Users/fadhil/Downloads/getpassenger.py", line 9, in main get_passenger()
File "/Users/fadhil/Downloads/getpassenger.py", line 27, in get_passenger passenger = login(username)

NameError: name 'username' is not defined

And also how to call this kind of function from another function? I have another function called order() and I wanted to call get_passenger() inside the order() function.

Code attached:

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Tropical Airlines Ticket Ordering System")
    print("Log in to the system using your username. A password is not required.")
    username = input("Username: ")
    login(username)
    ticket = input("This is the ticket for: ")
    if ticket == "you":
        ticket = get_passenger(username)
    else:
        ticket = "For someone else"

def login(username):
    print("Welcome, " + username)
    return username

def get_passenger(username):
    passenger = print("Dear " + login(username))
    return passenger

main()
```

Comment: don't put code in pictures, nobody want to type, copy-paste as text

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you didnt pass the passenger argument when defining the get_passenger() function, try this:

```
def get_passenger(username):
    passenger = login(username)
    print("Dear " + passenger)
    return passenger
```

and when you want to use the function do this:

```
get_passenger(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass username into get_passenger as well. username is a local variable, so get_passenger doesn't have access to it, hence the error.

```
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Tropical Airlines Ticket Ordering System")
    print("Log in to the system using your username. A password is not required.")
    username = input("Username: ")
    login(username)
    #After login, show the welcome message, and then the menu options
    get_passenger(username)
    #If any wrong input is made within the program, force the program to quit

def login(username):
    #Log in to the system using the username
    print("Welcome, " + username)
    #After login, show the welcome message, and then the menu options

def get_passenger(username):
    print("Dear " + username)
```

Also, returning username isn't doing anything here, so I removed it.

Comment: I mean like how to call it if it's not in the main function. I called the get_passenger() within the order() function

Answer (score 0):

Please change the function definition to:

```
def get_passenger(username):
```

and call it like:

```
get_passenger(username)
```